# Create Amazon S3 bucket only when tag is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have a requirement to create a bucket only when tag (name - Management and value - Test) is added to it. Below is the code which I written. But I am facing issues while creating bucket even I mention correct tag name and value.

```
{
    "Version": "1.3.2",

    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TaggingStatement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TaggingStatement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": "Management"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Management": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, please note that the `Version` in a policy should be `2012-10-17`. This is the template schema version, not a user-defined version.

I think the biggest problem you are facing is that there is **no capability to specify a tag** while creating a bucket.

For example, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3api create-bucket` command does not accept a `--tags` parameter. Therefore, it is not possible to satisfy the condition to have a tag while creating the bucket.

If you create the bucket through the console, it actually creates the bucket first and only after that adds a tag. Therefore, the first operation fails because it does not have a tag. You can probably examine this behaviour via **CloudTrail**.